# Uncountable-dimension subalgebra of a countable dimension algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, cardinals

Is it possible that a countable dimension $\mathbb{C}$-algebra has a proper subalgebra of uncountable dimension? I think the answer is negative but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you require a $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra?

Comment: Yes, I require a $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra

Comment: I expected as much (subalgebras are defined to use the same coefficients).  But now I'm wondering about the generalization to an $F$-subalgebra for some $F \subset \mathbb{C}$.  Hmm...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not possible. This is unrelated to any $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structure and depends only on the basic linear algebra fact that if $W$ is a vector space and $V$ is a subspace of $W$, then $\dim(V)\leq\dim(W)$.

Comment: In particular, if $S$ spans $W$ then $S$ spans every $V\subseteq W$. This fact follows from the definition of span and the result follows immediately from this.